# Failed to instantiate manager instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, metatrader4, mt4

I am using [this library](https://github.com/Uriil/MetaTrader4.Manager.Wrapper) to develop a asp.net web api for MetaTrader4, but failed to instantiate.
Here is My trial:

```
[Route("users/")]
public IList<UserRecord> GetAllUsers()
{
    IList<UserRecord> users;
    using (var metatrader = new ClrWrapper(new ConnectionParameters
    {
        Login = 123456,
        Password = "managerPassword",
        Server = "123.123.123.123:443"
    }))
    {
        users = metatrader.UsersRequest();
    }
    return users;
}
```

And the Exception is:

```
Failed to instantiate manager instance
於 P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.ClrWrapper..ctor(String metatraderLibraryPath) 於 P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.ClrWrapper..ctor(ConnectionParameters connectionParameters, String metatraderLibraryPath) 於 P23.MetaTrader4.Manager.ClrWrapper..ctor(ConnectionParameters connectionParameters) 於 mt4_api.Controllers.UsersController.GetAllUsers() 於
```

The Code is Ok when it runs under console project, but fail in asp.net web api project.

Can Someone helps?

Comment: You need to provide path to mtmanapi.dll as second parameter in ClrWrapper constructor

Comment: I include the mtmanapi.dll in the bin folder, and not working

Comment: Thanks a lot, I use the absolute path to mtmanapi.dll and problem solved